# Chat for StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request

Would be nice if we could have a little chat window–not the chatrooms– in where I can see my answers and questions? comment, edit, flag or another actions?

Comment: To chat with your answers and questions? Perhaps you meant a feed?

Comment: Ummm... what do you mean?

Comment: It would be like open a post, that would pin to the bottom of the screen, and allow to make all actions to that post.

Comment: @juanpastas A lot of people have developed [alternatives/extensions for the SO interface](http://stackapps.com/questions/972/stackbuffer-awesome-stackoverflow-interface-html5-css3) over at StackApps. If you feel it is worthwhile, you could look into making one yourself, or you could request something like this there.

Comment: That's not really chat then, is it?

Answer (score 2):

All of that information is on your [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/205281/juanpastas).

I am not sure how that is "chatty" but that should have everything you need.